# What is difference in user timeline, home timeline and friends timeline in twitter4j while integration of twitter API?

Tags: android, twitter

I was integrating twitter API in an android application and in that there is a requirement to fetch twitter timeline. So, i wanted to know about the twitter timelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Twitter API Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). You must be using an old library though as the 'friends' timeline doesn't exist anymore; now there's home (your timeline as you see it on twitter.com) and user (the tweets on your profile).